# pandas string comparison by splitting using value counts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to using pandas, and I'm attempting to create a method of matching strings in pandas that have low value_counts, and then changing them to match similar strings with higher value counts. I've tried splitting the strings, but I can't figure out the next part. What I want to do is check if the split strings which are longer than 2 characters exist in the array with higher value counts, and then take the highest value count match, so that all matching strings are the same for that column. There's about 18 different value counts, and my aim is to get this to the lowest number which should be about 10 or 11. It's from a larger dataframe, and there are a lot of similar groups to repeat this on. This is what I've done so far.

```
vc = data['event_name'].value_counts()
   str_arr = []
   for v in vc[vc < 10].index:
       str_arr.append(v.split())
```

Then I can manually check for the strings:

```
data[data['event_name'].str.contains(str1, str2)]
```

I'm not sure how to match and update in the data frame using a loop, and also ensure that the low value_count strings aren't included in the strings to match.

Comment: Could you please explain your question in short?

Comment: Sure, I'll try..how can I take a split string and search in other values for at least 2 matches. E.g. The split string [ "AB", "A longer string", "CD, "Another String"]. The string to match "A longer string CD Another String". I want to check if the 2 longer strings match, and if they do, change the value of the original string which was split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with

```
vc = data.merge(data['event_name'].value_counts().reset_index(),
                left_on='event_name', right_on='index', how='left')
```

to get the value_counts associated with each row of the initial dataframe, and replace your setup step with*

```
vc['long words'] = vc['event_name'].str.replace('\s\S\S?\s|\A\S\S?\s|\s\S\S?\z',
                                                ' ').str.strip()
```

to create a field with just the longer words, then you can follow up with

```
vc_max = vc.sort_values('event_name_y', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('long words')
```

to identify the most frequent value for each set of matching longer words, and use

```
vc.merge(vc_max, on='long words', how='left')
```

to match these to each row, which, since the index has remained the same, can be assigned with

```
data['event_name'] = vc.merge(vc_max, on='long words', how='left')['event_name_x_y']
```

---

*If you want to stick with lists/don't like regex, the below would also work

```
    vc['long words'] = [' '.join([string for string in split if len(string) > 2])
                        for split in vc['event_name'].str.split().tolist()]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost working for me. The regex version didn't match as many as the list version, but some of the shorter strings aren't always at the beginning, which could be the reason. The list version matched nearly all. I got a key error on the splitting line, which I resolved by changing to vc['event_name_x'] instead of vc['event_name']. The last line didn't work for me, and the data['event_name'] field was NaN, maybe because the index is from the larger data frame. There's some exceptions, such as abbreviations and extra words.

Comment: I added a line which has now resolved all the shorter strings, and reset the index after extracting from the main data frame, so now it works, thanks EFT.